# Which Javascript / Chrome Extension IDE are you using?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ide

I'm currently develloping a Chrome Extension and i'm searching for more ergonomy by finding a good IDE who can manage javascript and also Chrome Extension API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2) and add the following scripts to File references.

- [chrome_extensions.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js)
- [webkit_dom.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/webkit_dom.js)

[image: Add to File References]

Congratulations! You now have a very capable javascript editor with autocomplete support for chrome APIs

[image]

### EDIT

You can have the same functionality in Visual Studio, which has (in my opinion) even better support for javascript. In fact I think it's the best javascript editor around (quiet an achievement for microsoft :))

Just add the following comment to your js files:

```
/// <reference path="MyExternalFile.js" />
```

And you get:

[image: extern in VS2010]

Comment: Oh men it's so good !

I was already using aptana but boring because i was thinking they were no Chrome Extension... Thanks

Comment: I just found out you can do the same in VS2010

Comment: dang I tried to go the aptana eclipse plugin route but autocomplete isn't working :/

Comment: The links in your post are unavailable, the files exist here [webkit_console.js](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/contrib/externs/webkit_console.js) [chrome_extensions.js](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js)

Comment: [webkit_console.js](https://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/git-history/v20110119/contrib/externs/webkit_console.js)  Updated link..needs version tag.

Comment: @Jan your link for webkit_console.js chrome_extensions.js  are not working

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work on IntelliJ by using this API stub (to make the chrome object appear in auto completion)

https://github.com/linux-china/chrome_js_api_stub

In combination with the chrome extension.js

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js

I then added the stub chrome_js_api_stub library and the chrome extension library by following the below directions

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: This works great in Webstorm IDE. Here's an updated link to chrome_extensions.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js

Answer (score 1):

It's not for everyone, but if by ergonomy you mean moving your hands around as little as possible, not reaching for the mouse, VIM is very much designed to keep your fingers on the keyboard and as close to the asdf/jkl; positions as much as possible. It's a pretty steep learning curve, but the payoff is extremely quick workflow.

With the right addons, it's a very decent javascript editor, with syntax highlighting (including jsdoc comments), code completion, jslint integration, etc

Answer (score 0):

For Aptana Studio 3: (plugin for Eclipse tested)

Find a library you are interested in...Save it to your disk, and then drag it into your project. It does not matter where in the project it sits, so you can create a new folder for files like this if you like.

**!! The project must be some type of web project: Web, PHP, Python, Ruby, Rails.**

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries